# Following is a list of four records in a file data.txt

Tags: shell

The question is

Following is a list of four records in a file data.txt

| ID | First name | Last name | sub1 | sub2 | sub3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | ram | sen | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 111 | sam | gupta | 14 | 33 | 22 |
| 121 | jamie | any | 12 | 11 | 16 |
| 131 | nancy | rohila | 17 | 10 | 19 |

the first column is ID, second column is first name, third one is last name, and fourth, fifth, sixth are marks in diferent subjects

I have to write a shell script(info.sh) as

(i) if the program is run without any arguments, it will display the first name, last name and average of marks for each students

(ii) if the program is run with numeric argument(info.sh 121) , it will assume it as ID of student and will output ID, first name, second name and the average score of that student

(iii) if the program wil run with non numeric arguments (info.sh sen) then it will assume it as either first name , last name and output the ID's of al the students whose first or last name matches with the argument

(iv) if program will run with more then one arguments, it will display an error

I am able to achieve the first part using this script:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print $2, $3, "Average"; next }    # Print a heading row
     NF > 3  { sum=0; for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i; print $2, $3, (sum/3) }' \
     data.txt
```

But not able to achieve other parts
can anybody help or suggest

Comment: Can you show the actual input file format instead of a table?

Comment: @jitendra raj - If you meant "numeric argument" when you wrote "numeric arguments", you should correct that.